# Downloading Collected GPS Data from Trimble Nomad GPS on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: gps, ubuntu, trimble

I am wanting to use Ubuntu on some off network computers.  We will need to put background layers on the GPS and also download the data we collect.  When I plugged the GPS into the ubuntu 16 machine it was not recognized.

Can someone help me with the steps to get the GPS recognized?

It's a Trimble Nomad running Windows Mobile 6 Classic. CE OS 5.2.1946(Build 18550.7.4) Processor is ARM920T PXA3xx.  On Windows machines they use Microsoft Windows Mobile Device Center that establishes the connection and then it can be browsed like an external drive or cell phone in file browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 4 Trimble Juno's and tried the Windows Mobile Device center, in the end I found it easier to just use SD cards and a USB card reader, it's faster and allows you to drop/drag the files between the PC and GPS units. Many laptops also have a card reader built in.  Your Nomad should have an SD card giving you this option making it as easy as using a USB thumbdrive.

Comment: I know I am probably over thinking this.  I've used the SD card to this point.  That may be the method I have to keep using.  I'll keep this question up for a couple days to see if there is any more responses about how to get the usb GPS Connections because I could see that being useful.  If no more responses come I'll accept this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it is a valid solution.  I would love if someone knew how to make the gps units talk to ubuntu via usb.  Thanks for your input!